# Will this take advantage of multiple CPU cores?

Tags: node.js, sockets, http, nginx, load-balancing

My Node server with Socket.IO runs behind Nginx. I am load balancing it with Nginx. The client is directed to one of these ports:

```
upstream nodes {
  ip_hash;

  server localhost:2000;
  server localhost:3000;
  server localhost:4000;
  server localhost:5000;
}
```

My Node server is set up like this:

```
function server(port){
  const http = require(`http`).createServer((req, res) => {
    // http stuff ...
  }.listen(port)

  const io = require(`socket.io`)(http)
  // socket stuff ...
}

server(2000)
server(3000)
server(4000)
server(5000)
```

Does Node run each of these ports on a  different core, or what exactly am I load balancing here?

And should the socket code go inside or outside of the server function?

Answer (score 5):

The code you've posted will run a single server serving four ports on a single CPU core.

You can however run four separate servers on presumably four cores with a small change. Pass the port as a command line argument:

```
function server(port){
  const http = require(`http`).createServer((req, res) => {
    // http stuff ...
  }.listen(port)

  const io = require(`socket.io`)(http)
  // socket stuff ...
}

server(process.argv[2])
```

Then start them as:

```
node index.js 2000 &
node index.js 3000 &
node index.js 4000 &
node index.js 5000 &
```

---

Note: Node.js actually have clustering capabilities built-in. Read the docs if you want to explore clustering further: https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html

Answer (score 0):

No, it will not generally take significant advantage of multiple cores.  node.js is mostly single threaded.  Starting 5 servers all within the same node.js process does not give you any more threads or processes which could use the extra cores.  If your port 2000 server is running code in service of a request, none of your other servers can run code at the same time.  They will have to wait until the port 2000 server yields control back to the one node.js thread.  Then, another server can get a request and start executing and all the others will have to wait for it.

What you may be interested in is the clustering module which will actually start multiple node.js processes (all doing the same thing) and then requests will be distributed to the different processes.  You do not need nginx to use this type of clustering as the clustering modules does it all with node.js software.  There's one server listener and incoming requests are then distributed to the various clustered processes.

You can read more about it in this other answer from earlier today, including a reference to a very good blog post that explains how node.js clustering works:

[Node: one core, many processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38863931/node-one-core-many-processes/38864521#38864521)

While you yourself don't want one core, many processes, many of the architectural issues are covered in that question.